# o meu botao checkbox nao esta funcionando(posivelmente por causa do css)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Eu estou tentando fazer uma tela de login mas eu tentei fazer um  `<input type="checkbox" class="senhaMostrarOuOcultar" onclick="mostrarSenhaEOcultar()">` para que ele ocultasse ou mostrasse a senha, mas quando ele está sem o css funciona normalmente, quando eu coloco o css para de funcionar, eu clico e ele nao marca nao faz nada o css é

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
position: relative;
left: 490px;
top: 100px;
}
```

mas eu também já tentei

```
.senhaMostrarOuOcultar{
position: relative;
left: 490px;
top: 100px;
}
```

tentei pelo class e pelo input + o tipo dele mas por algum motivo não funciona e eu acho que é por causa do css alguem pode me ajudar

Comment: onclick="mostrarSenhaEOcultar()" cade o JS disso? E cade o Html ?

Comment: o codigo html que mostra o botao era so aquele primeiro codigo ja o js tem 
function mostrarSenhaEOcultar(){

    var senha = document.getElementById("senha");
    if(senha.type == "password"){
        senha.type = "text";
    }
    else{
        senha.type = "password";
    }

}

Comment: o id senha é so da tag de input da senha

Comment: @hugocsl alem disso eu deixei bem claro que é o css pq quando ta sem o css ele funciona

Comment: Você pode estar correndo o risco de cair no problema X Y. (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy) Se precisa de ajuda, aconselho que coloque todo o código para que possamos ajudar analisando a fundo todo o contexto!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como está o seu JavaScript, então vou te sugerir o seguinte código:

```js
function mostrarSenhaEOcultar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("senhaInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="senhaInput">Senha: </label>
  <input type="password" value="123456" id="senhaInput">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mostrarOcular" onclick="mostrarSenhaEOcultar()">
  <label for="mostrarOcular">Mostrar Senha</label>
</div>
```

Eu incluí duas `label for` para que você possa acessar o input clicando no texto.

Sobre o css, eu não recomendo que você defina posição exata, ainda mais utilizando Bootstrap.